# org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I am using Weblogic as my app server.
I deployed an exploded war file.
I can access the application successfully.

But when I try to save a particular edit.
I am encountering this error

```
Root cause of ServletException.

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class **org.mozilla.javascript.DefaultErrorReporter** from class org.`mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons
    at org.mozilla.javascript.CompilerEnvirons.<init>(CompilerEnvirons.java:48)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:310)
    at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.<init>(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
    at com.hof.mi.web.action.CompressorAction$1.A(CompressorAction.java:95)
    at com.hof.mi.web.action.CompressorAction.A(CompressorAction.java:165)
    at com.hof.mi.web.action.CompressorAction.combineAndcompressJSFiles(CompressorAction.java:129)
    at com.hof.mi.web.action.FiltersJSAPIAction.execute(FiltersJSAPIAction.java:65)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
```

THanks!

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to mess with the location of `rhino.jar` in your classpath. http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/2279752